# Staying overnight in Shanghai airport (PVG)

Tags: airports, shanghai, pvg

I arrive late at Shanghai Pudong airport from a domestic flight then have a very early flight the next morning to Taiwan. I have spent long layovers in the airside section of PVG airport, but this time I will need to wait in the landside section of Terminal 2 until about 6 am. I'm not expecting it to be particularly comfortable but does anyone have tips or advice?

Also, the airport is open 24 hours, but will I get kicked out or moved on by security?

Thanks.

Comment: https://www.sleepinginairports.net/asia/shanghai.htm

Answer (score 1):

According to [this source](https://www.sleepinginairports.net/asia/shanghai.htm):

> Overall it’s not a comfortable airport to spend the night, but there
> are plenty of spots. Airport staff and security are generally tolerant
> of overnight travellers trying to sleep at the airport.
>
> Landside is a lot less comfortable than Airside, with only a few benches and not much in the way of restaurants or amenities.

There is also the [T2 Max VIP Hourly Lounge](https://www.sleepinginairports.net/asia/shanghai.htm#airportHotel) inside the airport with hourly rates which might suit you for some hours of uninterrupted sleep.

Comment: Is security set up so that one can go 'airside' at night, even if one's flight is only in the morning?

Comment: Answering [my own comment](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/118527/staying-overnight-in-shanghai-airport-pvg#comment313084_118657):  no, it is not set up that way.